# Matching all elements in an array in an array of arrays with $all in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document which consists of documents like these:

```
{ "f" : [ [ 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ] } // should match because of [1, 2, 3]
{ "f" : [ [ 2, 1, 3], [4, 5, 6] ] } // should match because of [2, 1, 3]
{ "f" : [ [ 1, 2, 4], [4, 5, 6] ] } // should NOT match
```

In this collection, I want to match documents, which has an array containing 1, 2 and 3 in one of the arrays of the "f" field.

What I've tried so far:

```
db.mytest.find({ f: { $elemMatch: { $all: [1,2,3] } } } )
```

I expect this query to work but I do not understand why it does not. I does not match any documents.

```
db.mytest.find({ f: { $elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { $all: [1,2,3] } } } })
```

This also does not work.

```
db.mytest.find({ f: { $all: [[1,2,3]] } })
```

This works but the elements have to be in exact order. I want to be able to match when the input array is 2, 1, 3 also. One possible solution must be to always store elements in ascending order and use this query.

```
db.mytest.find({ f: { $elemMatch: { $elemMatch: { $in: [1, 2, 3] } } } })
```

This works but it matches all the documents containing any one of 1, 2 or 3. I only want the documents which contain exactly 1, 2 and 3 in a single array.

What is the query I am looking for?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the operators perform an exact match in case of embedded arrays. Not the most pleasing or optimal solution(you need to test it with the records in your collection), but one way of doing it is via the aggregation pipeline on the server side.

- `Project` an extra field for each document representing the "f" value.
- `unwind` the actual "f" field, so that we can match a single array
  elements.
- `match` the documents where "f" contains all the values in the input
  array.
- `project` back the temporary field for the original document.

Code:

```
db.mytest.aggregate([
{$project:{"temp":"$f","f":1}},    // maintain a temporary variable for projection
{$unwind:"$f"},                    // f:[1,2,3] f:[4,5,6] become separate records.
{$match:{"f":{$all:[1,2,3]}}},     // use $all to match all the elements. 
{$project:{"f":"$temp"}}           // project the temporary variable.
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for documents where `f` contains `[1, 2, 3]`. Try `db.mytest.find({f: {$in: [[1, 2, 3]]}})`.

The easiest way to find all the possible permutations is, unfortunately, to construct them in your program (if you're using Python, `itertools.permutations` will do that for you) and change your `$in` query to `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3], ...]`. It sucks.

Comment: This only works when I put the numbers in the correct order. db.mytest.find({f: {$in: [[2, 1, 3]]}}) does not work.

Comment: I am not looking for documents where f contains [1,2,3]. I am looking for documents, where one of the arrays in f contains 1, 2 and 3, in any order. That's why this query does not work.

Comment: @Disposer May you please check again? My mongo version is 2.6.4 and it does not match document { "f" : [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ]]} . I also do not see how it may possibly work since $in tries to _exactly_ match at least one of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

What about generate all permutations of your array and use in your query?? something like this:

```
db.mytest.find({$or : [{f: {$all : [[1,2,3]] }}, {f: {$all : [[2,1,3]]}}, {f: {$all: [[3,1,2]]}}]})
```

Perhaps this is not the efficient way.

Comment: This would take up too much space. Instead of this, I could always store the elements in the arrays in ascending order but I am looking for a solution for my current collection if there is one.